# Cannot install devtools in R on MacOS

Tags: r, macos, anaconda, package, dependencies

I am unable to install the `devtools` package using RStudio on macOS. I guess my problem are missing dependencies but by individually trying to install them, I just get more and more errors. Can someone help me?
Here are the error messages:

```
ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘zip’ ...
** package ‘zip’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘openssl’
```

And the same for: zip, fast map, diffobj, fs, commonmark, brio, ps jsonlite, rlang, gert, lifecycle, processx, cachem, fastmap, purrr, waldo, cover, ellipsis, use this, callr, roxygen2, testthat

For instance, I then tried to install fastmap manually and got a lot of other missing packages. But the essentials and bases are installed.

Comment: Are you installing it through Anaconda? Have you tried installing it outside of it?

Comment: No, I just tried with Anaconda. I will try it and see what happens